Vue 3 and Vitest focus input sets document.activeElement to HTMLBodyElement in test in composition API
Given a Vue 3 component
<template>
  <input id="input" type="text" @focus="handleOnFocus($event)" />
</template>
<script setup type="ts">
const handleOnFocus = () => {
  console.log('Component document.activeElement:', document.activeElement)
}
</script>

And test:
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { expect } from 'vitest'
import AarghOmg from './AarghOmg.vue'

describe('AarghOmg', () => {
  let wrapper: any

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount<typeof AarghOmg>(AarghOmg, {
      attachTo: document.body
    })
  })

  it('outputs activeElement', () => {
    wrapper.find('#input').trigger('focus')

    console.log('Test document.body.innerHTML:', document.body.innerHTML)
    expect(true).toBe(true)
  })
})

console.log
Component document.activeElement: HTMLBodyElement {}
Test document.body.innerHTML: <div data-v-app=""><input id="input" type="text"></div>

I would expect for the document.activeElement to be the input, not the body element. This works correctly in a browser, so is an issue with the wrapper and the test framework.

It would appear that Vitest doesn't actual interact with the DOM internals, so
wrapper.find('#input').trigger('focus')

is triggering the @focus event on the Vue component but not actually setting the focus on the DOM element in JS Dom.
The work around was to restructure our code to have a variable which maps to the focussed state and an input template ref to then trigger the events e.g.
Vue 3 component
<template>
  <input
    id="input"
    ref="input"
    type="text"
    @focus="handleOnFocus()"
    @blur="handleOnBlur()"
  />
  <button id="button" @click="blurInput()">Blur focus</button>
  <div v-if="isFocussed" id="is-focussed">Is focussed!</div>
</template>
<script setup type="ts">
const input = ref(null)
const isFocussed = ref(false)

const handleOnFocus = () => {
  isFocussed.value = true
}

const handleOnBlur = () => {
  isFocussed.value = false
}

const blurInput = () => {
  if (isFocussed.value) {
    // This won't actually trigger the blur event in the test
    // as in JSDom the input is not focussed to then blur
    input.value.blur()
  }
}
</script>


And test
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { expect } from 'vitest'
import Hooray from './Hooray.vue'

describe('Hooray', () => {
  let wrapper: any

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount<typeof Hooray>(Hooray)
  })

  describe('input focus/blur interaction', () => {
    it('and no interaction, input should not be focussed', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('#is-focussed').exists()).toBeFalsy()
    })

    it('and input focus triggered, input should be focussed', async () => {
      await wrapper.find('#input').trigger('focus')

      expect(wrapper.find('#is-focussed').exists()).toBeTruthy()
    })

    it('and button clicked, input should not be focussed', async () => {
      await wrapper.find('#input').trigger('focus')

      await wrapper.find('#button').trigger('click')

      await wrapper.find('#input').trigger('blur')

      expect(wrapper.find('#is-focussed').exists()).toBeFalsy()
    })
  })
})



